# Как передать массив объектов через ajax запрос и обработать на сервере node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript

```
//Клиент    
function myFunc() {
            let myData = [];
            menu.orders.forEach((item)=>{
                myData.push(item);
            })
          $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: '/api/getReports',
                   data: {data: myData},
                   dataType: 'json',
                   contentType: 'application/json',
                   success: function(data){
                       console.log(data);
                   }
               });
    }
```

//Сервер

```
app.post('/api/getReports', (req, res)=>{
  let data = req.body.data;
  db.collection('reports').insertMany(data, (err, res)=>{
        if(err) throw err;
    })
    res.sendStatus(200);
})
```

Comment: а в чем проблема связанная с этим кодом? кстати, `res.sendStatus(200)` нужно перенести на строчку выше, в callback

Comment: через xmlhttprequest решил эту задачу! на сервере data равняется undefined!